# Geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

A contractor hires out machinery.  In the first year of hiring out one piece of equipment the profit is £6000, but this diminishes by 5% in successive years.  Show that the annual profits from a geometric progression and find the total of all the profit for the first 5 years.

So far I have this...

Profit in the 1st year is £6000

2nd year: £6000-5% = £5700

3rd year:  £5700-5% = £5415

I'm unsure how to find out the common ratio of these terms using the general geometric formulas

Sequence : nth term = ar^n-1
Series: Sn= a(r^n -1)/r-1

Comment: $1-0.05 = 0.95$

Answer (score 1):

You are finding the next term by subtracting 5% of the previous term from the previous term, which is equivalent to multiplying the previous term by 95%: $a_{n+1} = a_{n} - 0.05 a_{n} = 0.95 a_{n}$. This should allow you to deduce what the common ratio is.

Answer (score 0):

$\overbrace{a=6000}^{\text{initial amount}}, \overbrace{r=0.95}^{\text{common ratio}}, \overbrace{n=5}^{\text{number of terms (years)}}$.

Now use the formula $$S_n=\frac{a[1-r^n]}{1-r}$$ to calculate $S_5.$

Comment: S(n) = a1 * (1 - r^n)/(1 - r)
S(5) = 6000 * (1 - 0.95^5)/(1 - 0.95) = 27146.29
Answer: £27146.29